# How to Send SMS and MMS using Ubuntu API

Tags: ubuntu-touch, ubuntu-sdk, phone, qml, sdk

Is it possible to Send SMS and MMS using Ubuntu API?

I've searched in the following documentation, but I cannot find anything about that. https://developer.ubuntu.com/api/apps/qml/sdk-15.04.1/

thx,

Comment: Recompile the `messaging-app` and adapt it. (sources are here: https://code.launchpad.net/~phablet-team/messaging-app/trunk)